# Get Twig to only show authorised parts of a page or menu

Tags: twig

I am planning on converting a website to using MVC and php.
I am planning on using the Twig template engine so that I can remove all code from the page templates, but I have hit on a problem, and that is with my menu. I only want a certain level of user to access each menu item.

I have a function which I call which returns true if a level is allowed.
So for instance if you have a level of purchase you will be allowed to see Menu Item 1, but not allowed to see Menu Item 2. For instance Sales would not be able to see the first two menu items.

I know that you cannot call functions or classes in Twig.

eg (my function is in a class called logon, but that shouldn't matter)

```
<?php if ($logon->user_access('purchase','accountant','poweruser')):?>
    Menu Item 1
<?php endif;?>

 <?php if ($logon->user_access('accountant','poweruser')):?>
    Menu Item 2 
 <?php endif;?>

  <?php if ($logon->user_access('sales')):?>
    Menu Item 2 
 <?php endif;?>
```

The question is how do I make a template in twig with this functionality without using php?
I am totally new to using a template engine.

edit...
@Yoshi

Ok I include twig in my index.php with

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/Twig/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then whenever I want to render the page I call a function from my core/view

```
public static function renderTwig($template,$args =[])
{
    static $twig = null;

    if($twig === null){
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../App/Views');
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
        echo $twig->render($template, $args);   
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I call

```
View::renderTwig('Home/index.html',[
            'css'=> $css,
            'name' => 'Dave',
            'colours' => ['red','green','blue']
        ]);
```

I set this all up from a tutorial I have been following called "Create php mvc project from scratch".

PS. I suppose in my renderTwig function I could send in variables which are used on every page and add it to the arg array for the page. That way I wouldn't need to add authentication to every page.

***Edit:***
I am making a small amendment here. Even though Yoshi's answer is correct. I had a small problem which I have now solved, and I thought I would share this.
In the twig template I am using it like this

```
{% if user_access('sales','purchase') %}Do something{% endif %}
```

The problem is that I don't know the number of items that are coming in so I need to use args, and this caused me a small problem, as the following line sent the string to my function, but only one item.

```
return $this->logon->user_access($roles);
```

The problem with func_get_args is that you cannot pass it to another function. It can only be read in the function that you send it to. So my small amendment was this.

```
return $this->logon->user_access($args = func_get_args());
```

Now the problem here is that it sends an array instead, but my php routines were set up to use args, and I wanted to use the same function in php that I used in twig. So what I did was to check if an array came in, I just looped through the array, but if a non array came in I checked the args. eg

```
public function user_access($levels)
{
    $bool=false;
    if(is_array($levels)):
        foreach($levels as $item):
            if($this->userlevel($item)==true $bool=true;
        endforeach;
    else:
        foreach(func_get_args() as $arg):
            if($this->userlevel($arg)==true $bool=true;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $bool;
}
```

So thankyou Yoshi

Comment: Just add the function as a [twig extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions).

Comment: Or pass the `$logon` variable to your template

Comment: True, but in case of such general functionality it's a bit of an inconvenience. One would have to remember to always, on each render, get and pass the `$logon` to the view.

Comment: $logon is not a variable. It is a class, and user_access is a function in that class that only returns true if you are at the correct level.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Obviously it's a variable storing an instance of the class. But that really doesn't matter. Be it a method call on an object, or a static class call, to transport it to the twig view, you'll need an extension or something callable passed to the view on each render.

Comment: @yoshi Surely the variable could be added as a global as you would need to check permissions throughout the whole system

Comment: I have had a look at that extension page and it seems quite complicated for a beginner. Can someone give me an example of how to send my class to the template using View::renderTwig('Home/index.html',[
   'css'=> $css,
   'name' => 'Dave'
  ]);

Comment: @DarkBee Yes of course! I tend to overlook that possibility.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Could you add the part of your code, where you set up twig?

Comment: @Yoshi. I have just edited my post to show you the code I use to call twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to add the function (or the object) to your views.

> **Disclaimer**: I think it's really bad practice to setup the twig
>   environment inside a static method of `View`. I'm just going along
>   with it, so to not over complicate things here. But if you're interested
>   in how to do it better. Read up on [dependency
>   injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html).

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/Twig/vendor/autoload.php';

// only as an example example
class AccessChecker
{
    public function user_access(...$levels)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class YourTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var AccessChecker
     */
    private $logon;

    /**
     * @param AccessChecker $logon
     */
    public function __construct(AccessChecker $logon)
    {
        $this->logon = $logon;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new Twig_Function('user_access', [$this, 'checkUserAccess']),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array ...$roles
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function checkUserAccess(...$roles)
    {
        return $this->logon->user_access(...$roles);
    }
}

class View
{
    public static function renderTwig($template, $args =[])
    {
        static $twig = null;

        if($twig === null) {
            $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../App/Views');
            $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

            // the extras:
            $logon = new AccessChecker();

            // with globals:
            $twig->addGlobal('logon', $logon);

            /*
             * {% if logon.user_access('purchase','accountant','poweruser') %}
             *   ...
             * {% endif %}
             */

            // with functions:
            $twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('user_access', [$logon, 'user_access']));

            /*
             * {% if user_access('purchase','accountant','poweruser') %}
             *   ...
             * {% endif %}
             */

            // with an extension
            $twig->addExtension(new YourTwigExtension($logon));

            /*
             * {% if checkUserAccess('purchase','accountant','poweruser') %}
             *   ...
             * {% endif %}
             */
        }

        echo $twig->render($template, $args);
    }
}
```

Note: You obviously only need to choose one method of adding the functionality. I'd suggest to go for the extension. This way, later additions can happen in the same place, without a need to change the *wiring up* code.

Comment: Ok I think I understand I only need to change renderTwig if I am not using the extension right? Also if I am using the extension where do I put the extension? Can I run the class from anywhere or should I make the class in the vendor/twig folder somewhere as it is an extension for Twig. The reason for the static function was because I was following a tutorial and didn't know any better.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams That's ok, really. It seems you're still learning, and it can be hard to decide where to put things. To answer: No don't put your twig extension into the vendor directory. That directory is off-limits. Use your own source directory (`/src` by convention). You probably need to setup auto loading. If you're using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), that's just a matter of [configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: I have been writing php for a number of years. Only started using php classes 2 years ago so still learning. However I had a head start because I already knew c++ so it helped with the object orientated stuff. However I have only been learning MVC php for 2 weeks, and also at the same time been learning asp.net too. When I get home in about 8 hours I will try your code and let you know if it worked. Can't look into it now as I have to finish some other work that my boss is after me for LOL

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Just leave a comment if you have questions.

Comment: I am a little stuck. I have added the class in the same file for now for testing purposes. I am getting no error, but it isn't show my text between the if statement. So obviously I am doing something wrong, but the fact I am not getting an error is good. I know getFunctions is running because I put an echo in there to test, but it doesn't seem to be running checkUserAccess. Going to keep on trying and will get back to you. PS had to change new Twig_Function to new \Twig_Function

Comment: @ThomasWilliams I won't be able to come back to you during the weekend, but if you still have problems on monday, I'll try to help.

Comment: I finally got it to work the problem was that you put return $this->logon->check_access(...$roles); but the function in $logon was called user_access so once i changed the function name it worked.

Comment: A typo on my part then ;) make sure to develop with error_reporting set to E_ALL. It should have reported the missing function.

Comment: I do have a question. I am thinking of making a folder src/ to put my classes in which are not models. So in this folder I will put all my classes and make them autoload. My question is where is the best place to put the src folder. Obviously I have Controllers, Views and Models in a folder called App so should I just add another folder here? PS if you edit  that one line I will give you a tick, as it might confuse someone else.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Updated. Id suggest putting the the src folder alongside the vendor folder. Put all your code in that folder then. Also have a look here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Thanks. One final question. If I wanted to add multiple extensions. Do I need to make a new class for each one, or can I add more functions to the class that I have I have already got?

Comment: Only use one, you rarely need more.

Comment: Hi Yoshi. I have made an edit to my question as I found a small problem which I have since worked out and hope my edit will help someone else. The problem was if you looped through func_get_args() in the function checkUserAccess it displayed everything coming in, but once passed to my function it wasn't working, as func_get args only works on the first function and can't be passed. Well it can only be passed as an array. So that is what I did. Your answer is still correct, but I had to make this change to make it work for me, and I hope my edit helps somebody else.